# Cannot edit calendar events for invitations received by mail (Nextcloud, via Thunderbird/CalDAV)

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, editing, nextcloud

When I create events *myself*, everything works smoothly and I can easily edit them at any time.

However, I **cannot edit events** events if the event was placed into the calendar **by accepting an email invitation** (in contrast to self-created events).

**I updated** the troubleshooting section based on further testing in the meantime, esp. regarding relevance of primary location of event in local vs. CalDAV calendar. **Update 2**: added Android experience.
It seems there are actually **two separate problems, one in TB and one in NC**:

- **genuine within Thunderbird** mail and calendar, since the problem occurs also without any Nextcloud component involved
- **within Nextcloud**, since invitation-based events cannot be shown and edited even on the NC web surface (indefinetly spinning wheel shown instead of event [rightmost Fig], but I cannot differentiate if this is an additional genuine Nextcloud problem, or if NC just fails to report an error secondary of the way Thunderbird writes the data to the calendar.
- **Android:** of note, I can easily edit the events I could neither modify in TB nor in NC!

**Setup:**

- Win-10
- Thunderbird 91.9.0 (32 bit)
- Nextcloud CalDAV calendars (that work nicely otherwise), hosted by an academic institution (usually very helpful, thanks!) and not under my administrative control.
- Android 12, Samsung One UI 4.1, Stock Samsung mail app

**I tried to**

- Right mouse click -> "edit" is grayed out [left Fig.]. Likewise, double-click - open - Window is lacking the expected "edit" button.
- change accept status (i.e. to rejected) since TB may protect me from changing accepted events without notice to the organizer -> *cannot* edit even after rejection or tentative.
- **change event to task and back to event** (now duplicated event) -> now I **can edit** the duplicated event, but I **loose information**, e.g. for an event series, as this keeps only a single one event.
- The problem is (in contrast what I previously thought) independent of where I save the event when accepting it (primarily local or CalDAV). But there is a difference for a potential workaround (case (a) and (b), cannot use a second level of indentation here):
- (a) If placed into WebCAL, I can copy-paste the event from CalDAV    calendar **to local calendar** -> **possible to edit**, but it    **looses information**: e.g. the start date is changed to the one occurrence I grapped for copy-paste, and the end date is set in the    original event to a specific date in 2023, but after copy-paste to   local calendar, the end date is set to "no end date").
- (b) In contrast, when I safe it **directly to a local** calendar, I can **neither** edit it in the local calendar nor after copy-pasting to a CalDAV calendar.
- All calendars are writable, there is no lack of disk space, and I can edit other self-created events in the same calendars.

When I go to my **Nextcloud calendar web surface**, I can edit self-created events by mouseclick [middle Fig.], but **I cannot even display (or edit) accepted events**, I see only a spinning wheel indicating "work in progress", but it never finishes [right Fig.] (tested on current Firefox and Chrome browser, on two different Win-10 computers so far). Therefore, I cannot exclude the problem is on the Nextcloud/CalDAV side, although this is not exactly the same as in TB (TB: can display everything but not edit; NC web: cannot even display the (existing and synchronizing) event).

I have found some more or less similar problems in other questions, but no applicable solution so far (e.g. the problem was a non-writable calendar etc., that does not seem to be my problem).

I appreciate that Android/Samsung mail app can do what neither TB nor NC accomplish, constituting a seemingly flawless "emergency workaround", but still painful to use your mobile to edit what the ergonomic desktop keyboard and screens cannot...

**I am grateful for solutions:**

- problem is primary Nextcloud vs primary Thunderbird mail/calendar interaction? Do you experience the same problem on Nextcloud web (known bug irrespective of server installation, or probably locally specific to our instance), and or on TB?
- Workaround without the risk of loosing information, esp. on events with lots of adjacent information or event series
- at best, of course, a real solution to stop this problem

[image]